# Uploading multiple photos to Firestore Storage in React results in same URLs or different URLs but with same photos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on a React app that allows users to upload multiple photos to Firestore Storage and receive URLs for each photo that is uploaded. However, I am running into an issue where all of the URLs that are returned are either the same or, if they are different, they still contain the same photo.

I have a function called handleFormSubmit that is called when the user submits the form. In this function, I am using a for loop to process each image that the user uploaded and uploading each image to Firebase Storage using uploadBytesResumable function. I then push a promise that returns a download URL for each uploaded image into an array called promises. Finally, I use Promise.all to wait for all the promises to resolve and receive an array of URLs for each image that was uploaded.

Here is the relevant code for handleFormSubmit:

```
const handleFormSubmit = async (
    e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>,
    data: UseFormHandleSubmit<FieldValues>,
  ) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const storage = getStorage()
    const imageRef = ref(storage, `image${user?.uid}`)
    const promises = []

    for (let i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
      const file = image[i]
      if (file !== null) {
        const storageRef = imageRef
        console.log(image[i])
        promises.push(
          uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file).then((uploadResult) => {
            return getDownloadURL(uploadResult.ref)
          }),
        )
      }
    }
    // Get all the downloadURLs
    const photos = await Promise.all(promises)
    console.log(photos)
    let category = getValues('category')
    let title = getValues('title')
    let description = getValues('description')
    let price = getValues('price')
    let name = getValues('name')
    let number = getValues('number')

    try {
      const { uid } = auth.currentUser as { uid: string }
      await addDoc(collection(db, 'user_product'), {
        uid,
        date: Date(),
        timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
        sallType: proDetales,
        category,
        imgs: photos,
        title,
        description,
        price,
        priceCur,
        location,
        name,
        number,
      })
    } catch (error) {}
  }
```

Based on my testing, the URLs that are returned are sometimes unique, but the photos that they correspond to are  the same  . This seems to indicate that the issue lies with how the image data is being processed in the for loop.

Can anyone suggest a solution or a possible cause for this issue? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by providing random ID inside of the for loop

```
        for (let i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
  const file = image[i]
  if (file !== null) {
    let RandomID = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
      let randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomData.length)

      RandomID += randomData[randomId]
    }
    const imageRef = ref(storage, `product/${RandomID}`)

    const storageRef = imageRef
    console.log(image[i])
    promises.push(
      uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file).then((uploadResult) => {
        return getDownloadURL(uploadResult.ref)
      }),
    )
  }
}
```